# Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance

Tags: next.js

I am working on nextJS project and getting `Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance. In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.`

Button code on which I am clicking and getting error

```
<Button
    disableElevation
    variant="contained"
    className={classes.askQuestion}
    onClick={updatePopupState}
    style={{
        color: "rgb(255, 255, 255)", fontFamily: "Roboto", fontSize: "0.875rem", fontWeight: 500, fontStyle: "normal", letterSpacing: "0.001rem", lineHeight: "0.875rem", textAlign: "right", color: "#fff", backgroundColor: "#0C71C3", textTransform: "unset", "&:hover": { backgroundColor: "rgb(21, 101, 192)", },
    }}
    startIcon={ <img width={25} height={22} src={askQuest} alt="ask ielts doubts" /> }
>
    Ask your Doubts
</Button>;
```

Function calling on clicking const

```
updatePopupState = () => {
    setIsAddingQuestion(true);
    if (sendAmplitudeData) {
        sendAmplitudeData("attempt_question", { location: "ask-doubt-cta", url: window.location.href, query_text: "", });
    }
};
```

modal that should be opened on clicking the button

```
{
    isAddingQuestion &&
    (
        <AddQuestionPop
            isAddingQuestion={isAddingQuestion}
            showSignupOnQues={true}
            toggle={handleAddingQuestion}
            searchTags={[]}
            selectedOps={selectedOps}
            selectedIds={selectedIds}
            closeModal={isAddingQuestion ? () => setIsAddingQuestion(false) : null}
        />
    );
}
```

I was expecting the modal to be opened, as I am getting all required props in modal `AddQuestionPop` but still getting the error.

I was expecting modal to be opened.